# managedCUDA: playing with 1D FFT

Tags: c#, cuda

I'm trying to implement FFT transformation of signal with CUDA in C#. I'm using managedCUDA library for that. I've implemented it, but it looks horrible and it is not efficient at all.

Here is my working code:

```
public static float[] doFFT(float[] data)
{
    CudaContext cntxt = new CudaContext();
    CudaDeviceVariable<float2> devData = new CudaDeviceVariable<float2>(data.Length);
    float2[] fData = new float2[data.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        fData[i].x = data[i];
    }

    devData.CopyToDevice(fData);
    CudaFFTPlanMany fftPlan = new CudaFFTPlanMany(1, new int[] { data.Length }, 1, cufftType.R2C);

    fftPlan.Exec(devData.DevicePointer, TransformDirection.Forward);

    float2[] result = new float2[data.Length];
    devData.CopyToHost(result);

    fftPlan.Dispose();
    float[][] res = new float[2][];
    res[0] = new float[data.Length];
    res[1] = new float[data.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        res[0][i] = result[i].x;
        res[1][i] = result[i].y;
    }

    return res[0];
}
```

How can I avoid of manual copying of my signal data into float2 array? And how can I avoid of reverse copying of complex data into single-dimension float array (just real part of complex number)?

I've tried for example copying there:

```
CudaDeviceVariable<float> devData = data;
```

as I found somewhere, but I'm getting wrong results :-/

Thanks a lot!

Juraj

Comment: orcening the second part of your question, please take a look at the answer provided by @njuffa, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535182/copying-data-to-cufftcomplex-data-struct. The first part i

Comment: Concerning the first part, what do _horrible_ and _inefficient_ mean?

Comment: By horrible I meant manual copying of arrays ;) When I compared times of processor FFT and GPU FFT it was 100x slower, probably for this reason. When I run it with without manual copying (but I got wrong results) it was just 10x slower ;) But it is short sample of data, I expect it to be much faster with longer data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pad the input array to the right size if you're doing R2C inplace FFTs. See also the CUFFT documentation, chapter 2.4. Data Layout, page 6. Conversion on host side is not necessary.
The following example code should point you into the right direction, whereas it is not complete, e.g. no cleanup at the end...

```
//Context creation not necessary if CudaFFTPlan is the first Cuda related call
//Cufft creates a new context if none exists and we can use it implicitly afterwards
//CudaContext ctx = new CudaContext();

float[] h_dataIn = new float[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

//Caution: Array sizes matter! See CUFFFT-Documentation...
int size_real = h_dataIn.Length;
int size_complex = (int)Math.Floor(size_real / 2.0) + 1;

CudaFFTPlanMany fftPlan = new CudaFFTPlanMany(1, new int[] { size_real }, 1, cufftType.R2C);

//Size of d_data must be padded for inplace R2C transforms: size_complex * 2 and not size_real
CudaDeviceVariable<float> d_data = new CudaDeviceVariable<float>(size_complex * 2);

//device allocation and host have different sizes, why the amount of data must be given explicitly for copying:
d_data.CopyToDevice(h_dataIn, 0, 0, size_real * sizeof(float));

//executa plan
fftPlan.Exec(d_data.DevicePointer, TransformDirection.Forward);

//Output to host, either as float2 or float, but array sizes must be right!
float2[] h_dataOut  = new float2[size_complex];
float[] h_dataOut2 = new float[size_complex * 2];
d_data.CopyToHost(h_dataOut);
d_data.CopyToHost(h_dataOut2);
```

Comment: I've tried to implement your code you suggested, but I'm still getting wrong result. When I run local FFT (processor) and when I run this code, there are different values. Here is screenshot of my result: http://goo.gl/551UJh When I run code I posted I get similar (rounding error) values.

Comment: Here is also screenshot of that 'working' code: http://www.image-share.com/ipng-2667-14.html

Comment: I doubled checked the code I posted, it gives the same results as MATLAB, so it should be OK. I also tried it with larger signals, everything is fine. Whereas the code you posted is definitively wrong, CUFFT does not expect complex interleaved input data for R2C plans as you did. So if your CPU code gives the same results as the wrong CUFFT code, your CPU code is erroneous, too...

Comment: ou, can you please post your Matlab code here? I definitely have to check my app. Btw, thanks a lot that you spent your time with that! I appreciate that a lot.

Comment: Thanks again a lot for your time. I checked that and you are right, your code is OK. I copied Java code into C# and had a bug there.