# How to change sub-matrix of a sparse matrix on CUDA device

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix structure that I am using in conjunction with CUBLAS to implement a linear solver class. I anticipate that the dimensions of the sparse matrices I will be solving will be fairly large (on the order of 10^7 by 10^7).
I will also anticipate that the solver will need to be used many times and that a  portion of this matrix will need be updated several times (between computing solutions) as well.

Copying the entire matrix sturcture from system memory to device memory could become quite a performance bottle neck since only a fraction of the matrix entries will ever need to be changed at a given time.

What I would like to be able to do is to have a way to update only a particular sub-set / sub-matrix rather than recopy the entire matrix structure from system memory to device memory each time I need to change the matrix.

The matrix data structure would reside on the CUDA device in arrays:
d_col, d_row, and d_val

On the system side I would have corresponding arrays I, J, and val.

So ideally, I would only want to change the subsets of d_val that correspond to the values in the system array, val, that changed.

Note that I do not anticipate that any entries will be added to or removed from the matrix, only that existing entries will change in value.

Naively I would think that to implement this, I would have an integer array or vector on the host side, e.g. updateInds , that would track the indices of entries in val that have changed, but I'm not sure how to efficiently tell the CUDA device to update the corresponding values of d_val.

In essence: how do I change the entries in a CUDA device side array (d_val) at indicies updateInds[1],updateInds[2],...,updateInds[n] to a new set of values val[updatInds[1]], val[updateInds[2]], ..., val[updateInds[3]], with out recopying the entire val array from system memory into CUDA device memory array d_val?

Comment: Do you have an actual concrete CUDA programming question to ask?

Comment: It boils down to: how do I change the entries in a CUDA device side array (d_val) at indicies updateInds[1],updateInds[2],...,updateInds[n] to a new set of values val[updatInds[1]], val[updateInds[2]], ..., val[updateInds[3], with out recopying the entire val array from system memory into CUDA device memory array d_val?

Comment: Do you mean in host code or device code? And is your matrix really in COO format?

Comment: I am still quite new to CUDA, so I am basically following the conjugate gradient solver sample from the CUDA 6.5 SDK sample library. The matrix is defined by the calls:  `cusaprseCreateMatDescr(&descr)` `cusparseSetMatType(descr, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL); `  The matrix is loaded into device memory by calling: `cudaMemcpy(d_col,J,nz*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)` `cudaMemcpy(d_row,I,(N+1)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)` `cudaMemcpy(d_val, val, nz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)`

Comment: This makes perfect sense with a dense matrix.  I don't think it makes sense with a sparse matrix.  It's not clear if you understand how CSR sparse matrix storage works (CSR is the format used in the cuda sample you reference).  I can change a single value in a sparse matrix from zero to non-zero which could require that nearly every value in 2 of the 3 arrays (csrRowPtr, csrValA) to be changed.  So I think the general case is difficult to handle and might require updating most of the data anyway. (unlike the dense case, in which you can make a surgical change).

Comment: the vectors d_row, d_col, and d_val, and the handle cusparseHandle get used in calls to cusparseScsrmv and cublasSdot... which I believe uses CSC format. I am not changing any entries that have a value of zero, I only want to change the value of entries that are already present and defined.

Comment: I understand that under CSR format (or its transpose, CSC format) there is one array to store the column location of each value and a second array that tells what indices in val represent the first value of each row. I know that this means that adding a new non-zero value is tedious and inefficient. That is not what I am trying to do. Instead, I only want to modify the existing non-zero entries to a different value. I have an array updateInds that tracks the indices in val that need to be updated. I just need to know how to modify the corresponding ones in d_val (on the CUDA device)

Comment: cusparseS**csr**mv expects the *matrix* to be in CSR format.  The *vector*, as well as any data passed to any CUBLAS function, is expected to be in dense format.  If you only want to change the *values* of non-zero locations, that is relatively straightforward if the values to be modified are contiguous in the csrValA array.  If not, you're going to be hop-scotching around.

Comment: Yes. The accession pattern will likely include several contiguous but disjoint subsections of the csrValA array. Eg. csrValA[0:99] csrVal[1000:1099] etc. csrValA array will have a corresponding array, valA, on the system side. I will have a tracking array, updateInds, that stores the indices in valA that change. I just need to know how to use it to update the corresponding entries in csrValA. E.g. the matrix structure is mirrored and tracked on the system side I just need be able to update the CUDA side without reupload the entire valA array each time i need to change a few blocks of values.

Comment: E.g. I have system side valA and its copy csrValA on the CUDA device. I change the entries in valA at indices 0:9 and 100:109. In want to then update the corresponding entries in csrValA at 0:9 and 100:109. How can I do that without recopying all of valA to csrValA?

Comment: A small kernel world probably be the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only want to change the *numerical values* of the value array associated with CSR (or CSC, or COO) sparse matrix representation, the process is not complicated.

Suppose I have code like this (excerpted from the CUDA conjugate gradient [sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#conjugategradient)):

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_val, nz*sizeof(float)));
...
cudaMemcpy(d_val, val, nz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Now, subsequent to this point in the code, let's suppose I need to change some values in the `d_val` array, corresponding to changes I have made in `val`:

```
for (int i = 10; i < 25; i++)
  val[i] = 4.0f;
```

The process to move these particular changes is conceptually the same as if you were updating an array using `memcpy`, but we will use `cudaMemcpy` to update the `d_val` array on the device:

```
cudaMemcpy(d_val+10, val+10, 15*sizeof(float), cudaMempcyHostToDevice);
```

Since these values were all contiguous, I can use a single `cudaMemcpy` call to effect the transfer.

If I have several disjoint regions similar to above, it will require several calls to `cudaMemcpy`, one for each region.  If, by chance, the regions are equally spaced and of equal length:

```
for (int i = 10; i < 5; i++)
  val[i] = 1.0f;
for (int i = 20; i < 5; i++)
  val[i] = 2.0f;
for (int i = 30; i < 5; i++)
  val[i] = 4.0f;
```

then it would also be possible to perform this transfer using a single call to `cudaMemcpy2D`.  The method is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535182/copying-data-to-cufftcomplex-data-struct/13536437?s=47|1.2400#13536437).

Notes:

1. `cudaMemcpy2D` is slower than you might expect compared to a `cudaMemcpy` operation on the *same number of elements*.
2. CUDA API calls have some inherent overhead.  If a large part of the matrix is to be updated in a scattered fashion, it may still be actually quicker to just transfer the whole `d_val` array, taking advantage of the fact that this can be done using a single `cudaMemcpy` operation.
3. The method described here cannot be used if non-zero values change their *location* in the sparse matrix.  In that case, I cannot provide a general answer for how to surgically update a CSR sparse matrix on the device.  And certain relatively simple changes could necessitate updating most of the array data (3 vectors) anyway.